# add an object in middle of the list based on the condition

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am having a sorted list like below

[image]

with the below code I have sorted.

```
             Comparator<MyBean> typeComparator = Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getType);

             Comparator<MyBean> costComparator = Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getCost);

             Comparator<MyBean> multipleFieldsComparator = typeComparator.thenComparing(costComparator); 
             
             Collections.sort(mbList, multipleFieldsComparator);
```

Now I am identifying the total cost of each `Type` with the below code.

```
Map<String, Double> sum = mbList.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(MyBean::getType, Collectors.summingDouble(MyBean::getCost)));
```

Here I am having total cost of each type. like `A = 109490.03` and `B = 4431.218`

Now I need to add this Total Cost object in middle of the `mbList` list.

My desired output should be like below

[image]

My whole code is like below.

```
             Comparator<MyBean> typeComparator = Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getType);

             Comparator<MyBean> costComparator = Comparator.comparing(MyBean::getCost);

             Comparator<MyBean> multipleFieldsComparator = typeComparator.thenComparing(costComparator); 
             
             Collections.sort(mbList, multipleFieldsComparator);
             
             
             Map<String, Double> sum = mbList.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(MyBean::getType, Collectors.summingDouble(MyBean::getCost)));
            System.out.println(" $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ "+sum);
            
            for (MyBean mb : mbList) {

                row = sheetType.createRow(sheetType.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
                cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                cell.setCellValue((String) mb.getType() + "-" + mb.getCategory());
                cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                cell.setCellValue(mb.getCost());
                cellnum = 0;
            }
```

**MyBean.java**

```
public class MyBean{
    private String type;
    private Double total;
    private String xxx;
    private String yyy;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Here my question is how can I add the `Total cost` at the end of each sorting value like After `A` Total cost needs to be added and After `B` we can add Total cost....

Comment: using this example, http://trevershick.github.io/java8/2015/12/02/java8-grouping-by-regex.html
I think you can build a regular express group by method, with will group you entries starts with A- or B- ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but instead of aggregating the sum directly, group by type first, and then calculate the sums for every sub-list:

a) group by type

```
Map<String, List<MyBean>> byType = mbList.stream()
                                         .sorted(multipleFieldsComparator)
                                         .collect(
                                             Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                 MyBean::getType,
                                                 LinkedHashMap::new, // preserves order
                                                 Collectors.toList()
                                             ));
```

b) calculate sum for each type

```
for (Entry<String, List<MyBean>> entry : byType.entrySet()) {
    List<MyBean> typeList = entry.getValue();
    double sum = typeList.stream().mapToDouble(MyBean::getCost).sum();
    typeList.add(new MyBean(entry.getKey(), sum));
}
```

c) flatten all the lists to one big list (they're already ordered correctly)

```
List<MyBean> listWithSums = byType.values()
                                  .stream()
                                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

here is quick draft of idea, there must be better solution than this but this will do the trick (will update this answer later to improve the code)

```
lastMatch = "", totalCost = 0;
for ( mbList i = 0 -> n) {
    currentMatch = mbList[i].getType(); // return A- or B- ...
    if(currentMatch != lastMatch){
        if(lastMatch != ""){
            > print totalCost; // to avoid printing Total cost at first row
        }
        lastMatch = currentMatch;
        totalCost = 0;
    }
    > print col name = col value
    totalCost += mbList[i].getCost(); // keep adding cost for your currentRegExrMatch
}
```

Comment: May I know what is `currentRegExprMatch`

Comment: based on your example it should stores `A-` for first run until `B-` comes. the idea is to calculate cost and print for your A- group till it changes to 'B-' and so on